# Regular expression to find a word divided into parts and mixed with numbers

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I wrote python code to scrape tables from a pdf. When the table has missing values for a whole row it shows the legend "Insufficient Data". After detecting the tables and splitting into columns, this legend gets cut (at different points for different rows/tables) and weird characters (most of the time numeric) appear in the middle.

How can I write a regex to detect all of them? Examples:  
--------------------------------------------------  
| column_1    - | column_2              |  
--------------------------------- 
| Insu1ff0icien | t data60         |  
---------------------------------  
| Insuff0icient | data60           |  
---------------------------------

The code I tried was this one, but then I detected that I am not catching all the cases:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.str.contains('Insuf', regex=False).any():
        df.iloc[index,:] = [np.nan] * len(row)
```

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't feel like there's enough information here to make a solution clear. It sounds like you have arbitrarily scrambled data but without a clear spec of all of the possible scenarios a row could be in, there's no way to "just" write a regex for that. Can you clearly describe the legal parameters for the strings which need to be matched? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are going to have to think more about the problem at hand, and it would be good if you could update your question, but I thought it was an interesting problem. Obviously, some RegEx could be used, but I thought a more flexible approach would be to create a list of potential unique letter patterns and then use `np.where()` with list comprehension to change the data based upon your list of letter patterns to look for, which you could identify when inspecting the data manually.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1' : ['Insu1ff0icien', 'Insuff0icient'],
              'column_2' : ['t data60', 'data60']})
insufficient_list = ['ins', 'Ins', 'nsu', 'suf']
df['column_1'] = np.where((df['column_1'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in insufficient_list if i in x])),
                      'Insufficient data',
                      df['column_1'])
df
```

output:

```
    column_1            column_2
0   Insufficient data   t data60
1   Insufficient data   data60
```

Comment: Thank you, David. This is a very helpful solution. Is this similarly efficient as a reg.ex.? My concern comes because I have to read about 170.000 pdf pages (each one with one table, and several of those with this legend on some rows)

Comment: less efficient probably (not sure how much), but I think it is a little bit more flexible. Why don't you try it out and go from there. If it is horrible performance, I'm happy to see if I can think of a good regex equivalent.